# How to reset (clear) theme settings

Tags: theme-options, theme-customizer

I'd like to reset (clear) theme settings (from customizer) while activating theme. For example a theme by default has red menu, links and links on hover. I use something like this:

```
 function clear_prefs( $theme_name ) {
     global $wpdb;
     $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'options';
     $wpdb->delete( $table, array( 'option_name' => 'menu_sidebar_color' ) );
     $wpdb->delete( $table, array( 'option_name' => 'link_color' ) );
     $wpdb->delete( $table, array( 'option_name' => 'hover_color' ) );
 }

 add_action("switch_theme", "clear_prefs");
```

But maybe there is more elegant and correct (standart for WP), not so 'rough' way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the solution, maybe it'll be useful to anyone:

```
function reset_mytheme_options() { 
    remove_theme_mods();
}
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'reset_mytheme_options' );
```